# Why is my method not running asynchronously?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asynchronous, c#-5.0, async-await

I'm running a test that should be calling a method multiple times without waiting for its result.  Here's my code:

```
 private async Task HandleJob(string params) {
        // do stuff that takes a minute
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        return;
 }

 [TestMethod]
 public async Task StartTest() {
     HandleJob("one");
     HandleJob("two");
 }
```

When I set a break at `HandleJob("two")`, it only gets hit after `one` has been completed.  How do I make them run asynchronously, so no waiting is done?

Comment: Are these operations actually asynchronous?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov - it's Selenium driving a browser - I don't think they are, but I'd like them to be!

Comment: @SB2055: The compiler will issue a warning that tells you exactly what the problem is and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't used `await` in the method at all. This means that the method will execute the lines synchronously. To actually yield back to the caller and let the remaining code run asynchronously, you need to use `await`, which will continue the method as a continuation on the targeted `Task` (as well as unboxing any exceptions and return values)

There are a couple of helper methods in `Task` to assist with this - my favorite is `Task.Yield()`, which will immediately return, thus an `await Task.Yield()` will spit out into a new thread and return all at once.

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task StartTest() {
     await Task.Yield(); // await yields control, and Yield will ensure the rest of the method starts immediately
     HandleJob("one");
     HandleJob("two");
}
```

If you want the individual subtasks to execute all at once, conglomerate them using `Task.WhenAll` and `Task.Run`

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task StartTest() {
     await Task.WhenAll(
         Task.Run(() => HandleJob("one")),
         Task.Run(() => HandleJob("two")));
}
```

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted, it works when the other answer doesn't

Answer (score 1):

Your asynchronous method `HandleJob` is not really `async` as `Thread.Sleep` blocks the current thread. Try using `await Task.Delay` instead. Note that `params` is a keyword and your original code won't compile. I've changed it to `parameters`.

```
private async Task HandleJob(string parameters) {
        // do stuff that takes a minute
        await Task.Delay(10000);
        return;
 }
```

In your start method you can return a single `Task` that gets completed when both methods are finished using `Task.WhenAll` as pointed out in one of the other answers. If you return the result rather than `await` it, then the caller of `StartTest` can determine whether he waits for the `Task` to complete or if he ignores it and it becomes a fire and forget situation. Because you are not using `await` `StartTest` will not need to be marked as `async` anymore.

```
 [TestMethod]
public Task StartTest() {
     return Task.WhenAll(HandleJob("one"), HandleJob("two"));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to `await` both the tasks:

```
    private void HandleJob( params string[] value )
    {
        return;
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task StartTest()
    {
        var task1 = Task.Run( () => HandleJob( "one" ) );
        var task2 = Task.Run( () => HandleJob( "two" ) );
        await Task.WhenAll( task1 , task2 );
    }
```

Comment: better, but note the `new[]` isn't necessary since the `WhenAll` method is defined with a `params` parameter

Comment: Thanks ! I haven't used it before, so was not sure what the overloads were :p

Comment: Thank you!  I tried this but HandleJob is running when I define `task1`... so I never hit task2 until it's done.

Comment: You should return a Task.Run(() => { } );